# Can I use an excel book in SharePoint as my eternal data source?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

Is it possible to use a data table from an excel workbook that's on SharePoint as an external data source to a workbook on my local drive or another location in SharePoint?
There is a massive excel document with a data table that I copy and paste into my own excel report each month, but it would be so much easier if I could set up a data source to automatically pull the table to my spreadsheet where I pivot it for reporting purposes.

**thanks for any assitsnce!**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to query for an Excel workbook that's on SharePoint directly into a local Excel document.  However, certain permissions or authentication may be required.  Depending on the year of your Excel (I use Excel 2016), you will access this feature through the "Data" tab.  It will give you an option for "New Query" and from the list you will select "From Other Sources," then "SharePoint List."  It will then prompt for the URL of your SharePoint website and give you three methods to Sign-In (Anonymous, Windows, or Organizational Account).  Now it depends on the security/access settings for your Sharepoint site.  If you don't have the permissions to access the site and read the list this won't be possible. Assuming you have access, "If your list is not already open, click its name on the Quick Launch. If the name of your list doesn't appear, click View All Site Content, and then click the name of your list."  Once it's properly imported, you can refresh the content by clicking "Refresh All" under the "Data" tab.

Hopefully that helps answer your question.  If not, please provide more details about your situation so we can be a little more specific.

Helpful resource (although it is for 2007, it is still applicable): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-a-SharePoint-list-2f5427b3-1b54-412f-a6c8-6ec6defd2536

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment. I use excel 2010, this is across the organization and they don't plan on updating anytime soon.

Do I then need to take the excel document that is already in our sharepoint folder and turn it into a list first? I also don't see any "SharePoint" options in my data options.

Comment: You should be able to use the Excel document in the sharepoint folder without turning it into a list, although if the following suggestions don't work you could try that.  The tab you need will actually be "Power Query" and the drop-down will be "From Other Sources," then "From SharePoint List."  The authentication options should be the same as I described earlier.

Comment: Ok so I did try to create a test data table and turn it into a sharepoint list in the mean time and after entering the folder location/name and clicking finish I received _"An unexpected error has occcurred, changes to your data cannot be saved"_
As for creating a data source right to my excel doc in sharepoint these are my other options:
**From- SQL Server > Analysis Services > XML Data Import > Data Connection Wizard > Microsoft Query**

Comment: There could be many reasons you're getting that error, but after a little searching it looks like these are some solutions that were successful in the past:  The Custom list should not contain any special charactor values as field name.  Example:  1) Location #, 2) @ Sales.

Comment: Another possible solution:  Change your view in SharePoint to only display like Maximum 1000 rows. (use the Limit in the bottom of the view definition screen)
Attempt again to export to Excel - this should work without issues (if it doesn't the problem lies elsewhere in your SharePoint and then you should have a look in ULS)
Change back the View to show all items or those you need.
Use the Refresh All in Excel to get latest updates from your View

Comment: I did see the first examples when searching forums, I am only trying to create a test list right now though. I have 10 columns across and 10 rows down simply numbered in progressive order, the column headers are just default "column1" through 10. I really do appreciate your quick responses and would much prefer to simply create the connection from the excel data source to mine if possible, any thoughts on the options in bold above? Perhaps this option is not available with **Excel 2010**?